# jQuery FadeIn not working for large image, even when preloaded

Tags: jquery, image, fadein

I am trying to use fadeIn with a large image, but instead of fading in nicely instead it's slowly appearing from top to bottom, line by line. I have used a script to preload the image as I thought that might help, but it doesn't.
The image is larger than it needs to be at the moment, but it shows what's happening more clearly.

The text block on the right fades in correctly, just not the image

You can see the problem here ... [test site](http://www.mrowiec.net/test/html/index.html) (if it works first time do ctrl-F5)

I'm using Chrome & IE11, and the problem occurs in both.

Here's the preload script I'm using ...

```html
(function($) {
  var cache = [];
  // Arguments are image paths relative to the current page.
  $.preLoadImages = function() {
    var args_len = arguments.length;
    for (var i = args_len; i--;) {
      var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
      cacheImage.src = arguments[i];
      cache.push(cacheImage);
   
    }
  }
})(jQuery)
 jQuery.preLoadImages("../images/Decoration.jpg");
```

... will this completely download the hidden image, before the next bit of jQuery starts to fade it in?

Thanks

Comment: The demo you posted works as expected for me. Have you tried viewing it on a different machine / browser / monitor?

Comment: It works for me when i reloaded the page, at first because I have a really bad connection it took too long for the image to load so didnt notice the fadeIn, suggest save as progressive jpeg for your images this will improve the load and should remove the line by line load you mentioned.

Comment: Hi, just tried it on my phone, it takes ages for the image to appear, line by line. Shouldn't the preloader download the image before the fadeIn effect begins? So it should be smooth?

Comment: I have re-saved the image as progressive, and it still downloads line by line :(

Comment: is there any way to tell if the image pre-loader isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

You should wait all needed images load, before doing fadeIn, something like this (I used [jQuery promises](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), for example):

```
(function ($) {
    var cache = [];
    // Arguments are image paths relative to the current page.
    $.preLoadImages = function () {
        var promises = [];
        var args_len = arguments.length;
        for (var i = args_len; i--;) {
            var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
            var promise = new $.Deferred();
            cacheImage,onload = promise.resolve;
            promise.resolve();
            promises.push(promise);
            cacheImage.src = arguments[i];
            cache.push(cacheImage);

        }
        console.log(promises);
        return promises;
    }
})(jQuery)
jQuery.when(jQuery.preLoadImages("http://placehold.it/3500x3500","http://placehold.it/3500x1500")).done(function () {
    jQuery('#myImage').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ps2hc98f/1/

Answer (score 0):

did some more googling and found a simple bit of code which seems to work ...

```
$('.img_content').load(function() {  
        $(this).fadeIn(2000, function() {
            $('.intro').fadeIn(2000 ); 
        });  
    });
```

thanks for your help